# Shifting values to the next day

Tags: pandas

I have this data frame:

```
ID      Date  X  123_Var  456_Var  789_Var
 A  16-07-19  3      777      250      810
 A  17-07-19  9      637      121      529
 A  20-07-19  2      295      272      490
 A  21-07-19  3      778      600      544
 A  22-07-19  6      741      792      907
 B  01-07-19  4      509      690      406
 B  03-07-19  2      413      725      414
 B  04-07-19  2      170      702      912
 B  09-08-19  3      851      616      477
 B  10-08-19  9      475      447      555
 B  11-08-19  1      412      403      708
 B  12-08-19  2      299      537      321
 B  13-08-19  4      310      119      125
 C  14-08-19  4      912      755      657
 C  15-08-19  4      586      771      394
 C  17-08-19  2      500      528      764
 C  18-08-19  1      982      383      654
 C  20-08-19  3      336      691      496
 C  21-08-19  3      206      433      263
 C  22-08-19  2      373      319      111
 D  10-12-18  2      170      702      912
 E  10-12-18  2      912      755      657
 E  14-12-18  2      373      319      111
```

I want to shift values in each column (among `123_Var  456_Var  789_Var` columns).

The value will be shifted only if there's a **one** day difference, otherwise, a `NaN` value will be remained.

The shifting should be applied for each ID separately. (by `Groupby`.)

Expected result:

```
ID      Date  X  123_Var  456_Var  789_Var  123_Var_S  456_Var_S  789_Var_S
 A  16-07-19  3      777      250      810        NaN        NaN        NaN
 A  17-07-19  9      637      121      529      777.0      250.0      810.0
 A  20-07-19  2      295      272      490        NaN        NaN        NaN
 A  21-07-19  3      778      600      544      295.0      272.0      490.0
 A  22-07-19  6      741      792      907      778.0      600.0      544.0
 B  01-07-19  4      509      690      406        NaN        NaN        NaN
 B  03-07-19  2      413      725      414        NaN        NaN        NaN
 B  04-07-19  2      170      702      912      413.0      725.0      414.0
 B  09-08-19  3      851      616      477        NaN        NaN        NaN
 B  10-08-19  9      475      447      555      851.0      616.0      477.0
 B  11-08-19  1      412      403      708      475.0      447.0      555.0
 B  12-08-19  2      299      537      321      412.0      403.0      708.0
 B  13-08-19  4      310      119      125      299.0      537.0      321.0
 C  14-08-19  4      912      755      657        NaN        NaN        NaN
 C  15-08-19  4      586      771      394      912.0      755.0      657.0
 C  17-08-19  2      500      528      764        NaN        NaN        NaN
 C  18-08-19  1      982      383      654      500.0      528.0      764.0
 C  20-08-19  3      336      691      496        NaN        NaN        NaN
 C  21-08-19  3      206      433      263      336.0      691.0      496.0
 C  22-08-19  2      373      319      111      206.0      433.0      263.0
 D  10-12-18  2      170      702      912        NaN        NaN        NaN
 E  10-12-18  2      912      755      657        NaN        NaN        NaN
 E  14-12-18  2      373      319      111        NaN        NaN        NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC,

we can groupby, apply a filter and use `.loc` along with `shift` to assign your values:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(pd.to_datetime,format='%d-%m-%y')

s = df.groupby('ID')['Date'].apply(lambda x : (x - x.shift()).eq('1 days'))

cols = df.filter(like='Var').columns.map(lambda x : x + '_S')

df[cols]  = df.filter(like='Var').shift()

df.loc[~s,cols]= np.nan
```

---

```
print(df)

 ID       Date  X  123_Var  456_Var  789_Var  123_Var_S  456_Var_S  \
0   A 2019-07-16  3      777      250      810        NaN        NaN   
1   A 2019-07-17  9      637      121      529      777.0      250.0   
2   A 2019-07-20  2      295      272      490        NaN        NaN   
3   A 2019-07-21  3      778      600      544      295.0      272.0   
4   A 2019-07-22  6      741      792      907      778.0      600.0   
5   B 2019-07-01  4      509      690      406        NaN        NaN   
6   B 2019-07-03  2      413      725      414        NaN        NaN   
7   B 2019-07-04  2      170      702      912      413.0      725.0   
8   B 2019-08-09  3      851      616      477        NaN        NaN   
9   B 2019-08-10  9      475      447      555      851.0      616.0   
10  B 2019-08-11  1      412      403      708      475.0      447.0   
11  B 2019-08-12  2      299      537      321      412.0      403.0   
12  B 2019-08-13  4      310      119      125      299.0      537.0   
13  C 2019-08-14  4      912      755      657        NaN        NaN   
14  C 2019-08-15  4      586      771      394      912.0      755.0   
15  C 2019-08-17  2      500      528      764        NaN        NaN   
16  C 2019-08-18  1      982      383      654      500.0      528.0   
17  C 2019-08-20  3      336      691      496        NaN        NaN   
18  C 2019-08-21  3      206      433      263      336.0      691.0   
19  C 2019-08-22  2      373      319      111      206.0      433.0   
20  D 2018-12-10  2      170      702      912        NaN        NaN   
21  E 2018-12-10  2      912      755      657        NaN        NaN   
22  E 2018-12-14  2      373      319      111        NaN        NaN   

    789_Var_S  
0         NaN  
1       810.0  
2         NaN  
3       490.0  
4       544.0  
5         NaN  
6         NaN  
7       414.0  
8         NaN  
9       477.0  
10      555.0  
11      708.0  
12      321.0  
13        NaN  
14      657.0  
15        NaN  
16      764.0  
17        NaN  
18      496.0  
19      263.0  
20        NaN  
21        NaN  
22        NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider this approach with iterrows():

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if df.loc[index, 'Date'] == df.loc[index-1, 'Date'] + pd.Timedelta(days=1):
        df.loc[index, '123_Var_S'] = df.loc[index-1, '123_Var']
        df.loc[index, '456_Var_S'] = df.loc[index-1, '456_Var']
        df.loc[index, '789_Var_S'] = df.loc[index-1, '789_Var']
```